# Class not found despite of classpath in MANIFEST

Tags: java, classpath, manifest

I have this jar:

```
/mybundle.jar/
    de/mybundle/myclass.class
    lib/mysql.jar
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

With the following MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/mysql.jar
Main-Class: de.mybundle.myclass
```

It all seems perfectly correct for me, but when I run

```
java -jar mybundle.jar
```

I get a NoClassDefFoundException when the class tries to instantiate one of the MySQL-Library classes.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have a mysql.jar file inside your main JAR file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bundle jar files in other jar files. The paths specified in the Manifest are relative to the location of the jar file you're calling, so in your case relative to the location of `mybundle.jar`.

You have two options:

1. Either put the MySQL jar in the lib directory outside of your `mybundle.jar`.
2. Create a *fat jar*, which contains all classes from the required jar files in addition to your own classes. This is available from within [Eclipse](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) or [Maven](http://code.google.com/p/maven-fatjar-plugin/).

Comment: Of course... I read that literally a week ago and thought to myself "hey, remember that! you're building jars next week!" .. d'uh! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your mybundle.jar is in c:/foo, then your mysql.jar has be in c:/foo/lib.  The Class-Path in the manifest is relative to the executable JAR the way you've written it.